# Plotting in sorted order using Plotnine

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, plotnine

I have a dataframe I am attempting to plot. I would like the data points to appear in sorted order along the x-axis in my plot. I have tried sorting the dataframe prior to passing it to ggplot, however my order gets disregarded. My data is as follows, I want to sort on the 'value' attribute.

```
       var1     var2  value     direction
0      PM25     PBAR  0.012001          1
1      PM25  DELTA_T  0.091262          1
2      PM25       RH  0.105857          1
3      PM25      WDV  0.119452          0
4      PM25     T10M  0.119506          0
5      PM25      T2M  0.129869          0
6      PM25     SRAD  0.134718          0
7      PM25      WSA  0.169000          0
8      PM25      WSM  0.174202          0
9      PM25      WSV  0.181596          0
10     PM25      SGT  0.263590          1
```

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
tix = np.linspace(0,.3,10)
corr = corr.sort_values(by='value').reset_index(drop = True)
p = ggplot(data = corr, mapping = aes(x='var2', y='value')) +\
  geom_point(mapping = aes(fill = 'direction')) + ylab('Correlation') + ggtitle('Correlation to PM25') +\
  theme_classic() +  scale_y_continuous(breaks = tix, limits = [0, .3])

print(p)
```

This produces the following plot:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OEBN.png)

Comment: By default, `ggplot2` will treat any textual element along the x-axis as a factor variable and will set the levels in alphabetical order.  To get the behavior you want, you need to make your `Variable` value to be a factor in the order provided.  And then try to recreate the plot.

Comment: But as I hit submit, I didn't realize this was a Python implementation.  The above comment is what you would need to do in R.  It may or may not still be applicable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in two ways

1. Make sure the variable mapped to the x-axis is a categorical and the categories are ordered correctly. Below I use the fact that `pd.unique` returns values in order of appearance.

```py
corr.sort_values(by='value').reset_index(drop = True)
corr['var2'] = pd.Categorical(corr.var2, categories=pd.unique(corr.var2))
...
```

2. Plotnine has an internal function `reorder` (introduced in v0.7.0) which you can use inside an `aes()` call to change the order of values of one variable based on the values of another variable. See the documentation for [reorder](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.mapping.aes.html#plotnine.aes) at the bottom of the page.

```py
# no need to sort values
p = ggplot(data = corr, mapping = aes(x='reorder(var2, value)', y='value')) +\
...
```

Comment: The link to the reorder documentation is dead, could you update? The first answer doesn't actually sort anything (the lines don't have any effect) so I would like to try reorder

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `reorder()` to work but I was able to use `scale_x_discrete()` to control the order.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578556/7685

Comment: This was worked for me