# How to reorder or sort categories based on another variable values in python plotnine?

Tags: python, plotnine

I am trying to use `plotnine` in `python` and couldn't do `fct_reorder` of `r` in `python`. Basically I would like to plot categories from the categorical variable to arrange on x axis based on the increasing value from another variable but I am unable to do so.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *
```

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'catg': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                       'val': [3,1,7,2,5]})

test_df['catg'] = test_df['catg'].astype('category')
```

When I sort & plot this based on `.sort_values()` then it doesn't rearrange the categories on `x axis`:

```
test_df = test_df.sort_values(by = ['val']).reset_index(drop=True)

(ggplot(data = test_df, 
           mapping = aes(x = test_df.iloc[:, 0], y = test_df['val']))
+ geom_line(linetype = 2) 
+ geom_point() 
+ labs(title = str('Weight of Evidence by ' + test_df.columns[0]),
            x = test_df.columns[0],
            y = 'Weight of Evidence') 
+ theme(axis_text_x= element_text(angle = 0))
)
```

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

I saw this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507299/plotting-in-sorted-order-using-plotnine) where they are using `reorder` but I couldn't find any reorder in plotnine to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotnine does have [reorder](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.mapping.aes.html#plotnine.mapping.aes). It is an internal function available when creating and aesthetic mapping, just like `factor`.

In your example you could use it like this:

```py
ggplot(data=test_df, mapping=aes(x='reorder(catg, val)', y='val'))
```

Comment: thanks, I wanted to use x as dynamic variable inside a def function & `'reorder(test_df.iloc[:, 0], val)'` worked for me.